# Why does QGIS use negative Y spacing in the default raster geotransform?

Tags: qgis, gdal

When loading a raster dataset that does not have a geotransform, QGIS overwrites GDAL default geotransform to use a negative Y spacing instead of positive.

This is done in [qgisgdalprovider](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/055a166136f29972571944bc741fbc68af42b4ea/src/providers/gdal/qgsgdalprovider.cpp#L609), here:

```
if ( GDALGetGeoTransform( mGdalDataset, mGeoTransform ) != CE_None )
{
    // if the raster does not have a valid transform we need to use
    // a pixel size of (1,-1), but GDAL returns (1,1)
    mGeoTransform[5] = -1;
}
```

Why? It can be a problem for example if you process such raster data with GDAL, and produce vector data to display later in QGIS, they will not overlap (regardless of CRS).

I realize that the identity geotransform will not happen in real data, but the topic of the default geotransform is important enough that I'm curious why QGIS made that decision. See [here](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/524) or [here](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2013-December/037714.html) for example.

Comment: this is to handle the fact the image origin is in the top/left and geographic origin is bottom/left corner.

Comment: The thing is that vector data do not have geotransforms (i.e it's always the identity) so these defaults are a bit inconsistent, and can bite you if you process such data. But I understand that it's nice that random png images show up not flipped for example.

Comment: I wonder the comment about the positive pixel size. https://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html considers north-up images as normal ones.